# configuration of TabHost using getDrawable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, drawable

I have a problem when calling `getDrawable()` in the `MainActivity`, I'm already done with `activity_main.xml`, but it shows this warning "the method `getDrawable(int)` from the type resources is deprecated".

Can anyone help me?

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res= getResources();
         TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
         tabs.setup();
         TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("pestana 1");
         spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
         spec.setIndicator("1",res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.bottom_bar));
         tabs.addTab(spec);

         tabs.setup();
         TabHost.TabSpec spec1 =tabs.newTabSpec("pestana 2");
         spec1.setContent(R.id.tab2);
         spec.setIndicator("2",res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_minus));
         tabs.addTab(spec1);

         tabs.setup();
         TabHost.TabSpec spec2 =tabs.newTabSpec("pestana 3");
         spec2.setContent(R.id.tab3);
         spec.setIndicator("3",res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio));
         tabs.addTab(spec2);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tabhost1.MainActivity">

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="pestana 1"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pesana 2"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pesana 3"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me?

There is nothing wrong with calling `getDrawable()`. For ~99% of Android devices, it is your only option.

In Android 5.1, they added [a second `getDrawable()` method, one that takes a theme as a second parameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme%29). They then marked the single-parameter version of `getDrawable()` as deprecated.

If your `minSdkVersion` is 22, use the two-parameter version of `getDrawable()`.

If your `minSdkVersion` is less than 22, continue using the single-parameter version of `getDrawable()`, and live with the deprecation notice.